# Background-color not displayed in some Outlook Mailing Clients

Tags: html, outlook

I have a mailer (HTML newsletter) which is rendered correctly across major Mailing Client. The only problem is with Outlook 2013 (and 2011), which will not recognize the background color. My code is something like this:

```
<center style="background-color: #801e53">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="589" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<img alt="To view our full e-mail, please enable the loading of images." width="589" height="135" style="display: block" src="header.jpg" />
</td>
</tr>        
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
```

Can you please tell me what I can do?

Comment: try adding it to your table vs center

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in outlook:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="background-color:#801e53;">

<!-- YOUR CENTERED TABLE -->

</body>
</html>
```

Colors the whole background.